# How to create a Mysql Query that returns something in that row and find other questions like it

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a Mysql Query where I can put an iframe on any page on the internet and it can find the page address and check if that is in the database. If so I must return a value from other rows that have the same variable in common.

1. Find the page Address
2. Check if it is in the Database
3. **If true** Return a value from that row
4. Find the 5 closest rows that have the same value.

Lastly I must be able to turn these into variables and display these as text in a php format.

Any help with this would be appreciated but, I realize that this is complex and If you have an answer to any of the questions here please answer.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take care of the first 3 for you:

```
$full_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$query = "SELECT url FROM tableWithURL WHERE url = '$full_url'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

}
```